# vector or map, which one to use?

Tags: c++, performance, stl

I've heard many people say that if the number of expected elements in the container is relatively small, it is better to use `std::vector` instead of `std::map` even if you were to use the container for lookups only and not iterating.

What is the real reason behind this?

Obviously the lookup performance of `std::map` cannot be worse than `std::vector` (although it may differ in nanoseconds/microseconds) so does it have something to do with memory usage?

Does `std::vector` fare any better/worse than `std::map` in fragmenting the virtual address space?

I am using the STL library that comes along with Visual Studio (i.e. Microsoft's implementation).  Does that make any difference compared to other implementations?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I presume you're comparing `map<A, B>` with `vector<pair<A, B> >`.

Firstly, finding an item in a very small vector can easily be faster than the same thing in a map, because all the memory in a vector is always contiguous (and so plays more nicely with computers' caches and such things), and the number of comparisons needed to find something in a vector might be about the same as for a map. Finding an element in a map needs fewer operations in the limit of very large containers.

The point where maps become faster than vectors depends on the implementation, on your processor, what data is in the map, and subtle things like what memory is in the processor's cache. Typically, the point where map becomes faster would be about 5-30 elements.

An alternative is to use a hash container. They are often named `hash_map` or `unordered_map`. Classes named `hash_map` are not part of the official standard (and there are a few variants out there); `std::tr1::unordered_map` is. A hash map is often faster than a normal map for lookups, regardless of how many elements are in it, but whether it is actually faster depends on what the key is, how it is hashed, what values you have to deal with, and how the key is compared in std::map. It doesn't keep things in a specific order like std::map, but you've said that you don't care about that. I'd recommend hash maps particularly if the keys are integers or pointers, because these hash very quickly.

Comment: Strangely I found Java's HashMap is much faster than the C++ Map. The last paragraph of your post possibly describes why.

Comment: @wmac: Right: it's more accurate to compare Java's `HashMap` to C++ `hash_map` or `unordered_map`, and Java's `SortedMap` to C++ `map`.

Comment: When I benchmarked I found the point where an std::map out paces an std::vector to be around 8000, but as low as a 1000 on some hardware, the code I used is available at: https://github.com/BlackToppStudios/DAGFrameScheduler/blob/8bfaa295b76f8e58dd4fc21186e1c7f3dd3e323a/tests/dagsizestests.h

Comment: "the point where map becomes faster would be about 5-30 elements" -- are you assuming a linear search or a binary search for your elements?

Answer (score 34):

"By default, use vector when you need a container" - Bjarne Stroustrup.

Otherwise, I find this little flow chart to be of very good help (**edited** - probably a valid live new link):

https://ngoduyhoa.blogspot.com/2015/06/summary-of-different-containers.html

Comment: According to Herb Sutter (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm), given a choice between deque and vector it is usually better to choose deque.

Comment: deque is nice because it is almost as fast as a vector but because the blocks of the deque are allocated independently it doesn't need to move everything in order to grow.

Comment: Link seems dead... you have another source ?

Comment: Dead indeed. This seems to be the original chart (to be confirmed): https://ngoduyhoa.blogspot.com/2015/06/summary-of-different-containers.html

Answer (score 30):

Maps are usually implemented as binary search trees, and walking a binary tree always comes with a little overhead (performing comparisons, walking links, etc.) Vectors are basically just arrays. For very small amounts of data, maybe 8 or 12 elements, sometimes it's faster just to do a linear search over an array than to walk a binary search tree.

You can run some timings yourself to see where the break-even point is -- time a search over four elements, then eight, then sixteen, and so on to find the sweet spot for your particular implementation of the STL.

Maps do tend to have a bunch of small allocations all over the heap, whereas vectors are  contiguous so the cache-hit rate of vectors can sometimes be a little better in cases where you're iterating over all the elements from front to back.

Comment: You don't even have to do a linear search. std::lower_bound gives you binary search on any sorted container. Map is useful when there's alot of key insertions, altering the structure of the search tree. If it's a fairly static collection, then a sorted vector and lower_bound would easily match map in performance beyond just a few elements. Ofcourse still worth a comparison in practise!

Answer (score 9):

If you're doing all your insertions at once then doing lots of lookups, you can use a vector and sort it when you're through inserting; then use lower_bound to do a quick lookup.  It might be faster than using a map, even for large numbers of items.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use the container that fits the data first and foremost. std::vector is used in situations where you would use an array in C or pre-STL C++: you want a contiguous block of memory to store values with fast constant time look-up. std::map should be used to map keys to values. The primary overlap here is a vector vs a map with a size_t as the key. In that case there are two concerns: are the indexes continuous? If not, you will probably be wasting memory with a vector. Second, what look-up time do you want? A vector has constant time lookup, while std::map is usually implemented as a RB tree, which has a O(log n) look-up time, and even a hash map (such as TR1 unordered_map) usually has a worse complexity, because the index (or a hash thereof) will be mapped to a bucket that can contain multiple values.

If were aiming at a vector with pairs: you could the elements of the vector and use find to find elements. But this is a binary search, and will practically be as fast as a std::map.

Anyway, try to model the data in the obvious manner. Premature optimization often doesn't help much.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to look at this, is if we're talking about small containers, then neither one is going to take very long to look up.  Unless you're searching through this container on a very tight loop, the difference in time will probably be negligible.

In that case, I would look for which container more closely matches what you want to do.  If you're looking for a particular value, map's built-in find() method will be a lot easier (and less complex to use) than creating a for loop and iterating over a vector.

Your own time is probably worth a lot more than a few nano-seconds here and there.

Comment: Yes, I agree that CPU time saved is not worth the effort. But what about memory consumption?

Comment: I generally agree, but note that the std::find() algorithm operates quite happily with both maps and vectors.

Comment: If we're talking about a small amount of entries then memory consumption will be low overall...what's a few bytes?  What are we talking about here...twenty?

Map has a built-in find...a little easier than std::find().

Answer (score 0):

Basically, maps are used for lookup.

But, sometimes `std::vector` can be used instead of `std::map` even for look up.

If there are going to be very less elements in your key-value pairs, then you can go for an iterative search using key even in `std::vector<std::pair<x,y>>`.

This is because of the fact that hashing takes time, especially for hashing strings and for other operations in map like storing data in heap.

You would only see a better difference in std::map, if you have more elements in which you have to lookup and also when you want to do frequent lookup in the list of elements that you have.

Comment: std::map doesn't use a hash for lookup. by default it uses std::less as a comparator