# Parallel arrays to create a database to store animal types and counts for C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, computer-science

[This is what it's suppose to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Krl.png)

Am I doing this correctly? and what another coding I need to do to display like this. I have to simulate a database to store animal types and animal type count. I have to use parallel arrays for data storage. It would be better if I make this dynamically allocated array of no mroe than 5 elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_RECORDS = 5;
const int ADD = 1, DISPLAY = 2, EXIT = 3;

void addAnimal();
void displayAnimal();

int main()
{
    int choice, animal;
    int a = 0;

    do 
    {
        cout << "How many animal records would you like to store (5 max): ";
        cin >> animal;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "1. Add animal(s)" << endl;
        cout << "2. Display animals" << endl;
        cout << "3. Quit" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter a menu number: ";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice <= 0 || choice > EXIT)
            {
                cout << "Error. Please try again.\n";
                cout << endl;
            }
        } while (choice <= 0 || choice > EXIT);

        // Create a muliway branch statement.
        switch (choice)
        {
        case ADD:
            addAnimal();
            break;
        case DISPLAY:
            displayAnimal();
            break;
        case EXIT:
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != EXIT);
        
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void addAnimal()
{
    string str;
    do
    { 
        cout << "Please enter an animal type (none to stop): " << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
        cout << "Enter the animal type's count: " << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
    } while (str != "goodbye");
    
}
void displayAnimal()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good way to achieve what you want is to inculcate Object-Oriented programming into this. Here is a simple [structure](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/structure) of Animals that can be used to create an array of 5 objects.

Take this short example

```
#include<iostream>

struct Animal{
    std::string name;
    int value;
    int weight;
}animals[5]; // creates an animal object array of size 5


int main(){
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++){
        std::cout << "Name of animal number " << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> animals[i].name;
    }
    std::cout << animals[0].name;
}
```

Output:

```
Name of animal number 1: Tiger
Name of animal number 2: Lion
Name of animal number 3: Kangaroo
Name of animal number 4: Cheetah
Name of animal number 5: Dog
Tiger
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 23.463 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Information on what is going on in this program.

When I say `struct Animal` I am creating a [structure](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/structure). Animals all have similar features like weight, color, name etc. Those are the variables that will be present inside the body of the structure.

`animals[5]'. Think of this as an array of animals. Animals that have common attributes like weight, color, name etc. Assume the user wants to create a new animal and enter it's features. I can use one element from the array to do this. Let's use the first one.

```
std::cout << "Enter name: ";
std::cin >> animals[0].name;
std::cout << "Enter weight: ";
std::cin >> animals[0].weight;
std::cout << "Enter value: ";
std::cin >> animals[0].value;
```

Now the first element of `animals` has been initialised. You can access it by `animals[0].attribute`

This approach will work effeciently for this kind of a program. Refer to [this](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/structure).

In my example I have taken input of all 5 elements using a loop. You can do the same when the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, I would suggest you use `std::vector<>`.Below is a basic implementation of using [vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/) in C++.

**Note**: You need to mention `#include<vector>` at the top.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> my_vec; // initializing a vector of integers
    // To add anything to a vector, you can use
    my_vec.push_back(5); // Adds 5 to my_vec
    my_vec.push_back(6); // Adds 6 to my_vec
    
    std::cout << my_vec[0] << std::endl; // Slicing from a vector
    for(auto it:my_vec) std::cout << it << std::endl; // display contents
    return 1;
}
```

I cannot show you everything about vectors in this answer, it's another huge topic. The main idea is that they are dynamic and can change size during run-time. compared to traditional static arrays.

[vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/) in C++

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using an `std::map`. You can add as many animals as you want. Each animal name, in this case, will have an associated count. In the example below, when the program exits, it will print out everything that you added to the map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> animal_database;
    std::string animal_name;
    std::string animal_count;
    std::string in_val;


    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an animal name: ";
        std::cin >> animal_name;
        std::cout << "Enter animal count: ";
        std::cin >> animal_count;
        animal_database.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(animal_name, std::stoi(animal_count)));
        std::cout << "Would you like to to add another animal?: [Y] or [N] ";
        std::cin >> in_val;
        if (in_val == "N" || in_val == "n")
            break;
    }

    for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = animal_database.begin(); it != animal_database.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maps aren't suitable here. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454762/vector-or-map-which-one-to-use)

Comment: @AryanParekh Agreed that with a data set this small a vector will be a more optimal choice. My thinking was to have an animal 'database'. In this instance, the key value pair seemed useful. Retrieving the quantity of 'cat' using the key 'cat' seemed more meaningful than access 'cat' at index 3.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, OOP would be a nice approach @ptan90